Python Tkinter - Frames won't display when i write the code to change the icon?
I have code to add 3 separate header, body, and footer frames into my window. These work perfectly fine until i write "winHome.iconbitmap("uqicon.ico")". This code also works fine on it's own but for some reason taking it out makes the frames appear and leaving it in prevents them from appearing. If anybody knows a way to fix this that would be great, or even provide a better way to fix my header/footer problem as im a beginner.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk  
from tkinter import messagebox

winHome = Tk()

winHome.title("Log In")

winHome.geometry("1000x800+50+50")
winHome.resizable(False,False) 

#import the image uqicon.ico as the icon
winHome.iconbitmap("uqicon.ico")

header = tk.Frame(winHome, bg='#4B2D72')
content = tk.Frame(winHome, bg='#f5f5f2')
footer = tk.Frame(winHome, bg='#4B2D72')

winHome.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # 100%
winHome.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)     # 10%
winHome.rowconfigure(1, weight=8)     # 80%
winHome.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)     # 10%

header.grid(row=0, sticky='news')
content.grid(row=1, sticky='news')
footer.grid(row=2, sticky='news')


winHome.mainloop() ```


Do you get any error message?

@Derek No i did not. It ran as if i had just defined an empty window

Try using winHome.iconbitmap(default = "uqicon.ico")
